# Minimum Spring version compatible with Java 11

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-11

I need to upgrade an app to Java 11 very soon, I was wondering what's the minimum Spring version that is compatible with Java 11.

I'm currently using Java 8 and Spring 4.2.7.

Comment: Given that Java 11 hasn't been released I don't see how this can be answered.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From their task tracker -- ***[SPR-16391:Compatibility with JDK 11](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16391)***. The compatibility of JDK 10, 11 is planned along with ***5.1 GA*** release.

> JDK 11 is currently scheduled for September 2018. Not expecting any
>   major changes beyond JDK 10 from our perspective, *we should be able to
>   fully support it in the 5.1 line already.*
>
> Ideally our framework build would be able to run on JDK 8, 9, 10 as
>   well as 11, even if our own test efforts will focus on JDK 8 and 11
>   (as the official long-term support branches) at that point.

While the option of experimenting with your own code on module path is still feasible using spring framework 5.0, which [provides out-of-the-box support for JDK 9 already](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/overview.html#spring-introduction).

***Update:*** [Spring Framework 5.1 goes GA on 21st September, 2018](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/21/spring-framework-5-1-goes-ga)

Answer (score 24):

Spring Boot version 2.1.0 [has been released](https://spring.io/blog/2018/10/30/spring-boot-2-1-0) with full Spring 5.1 and Java 11 support.

> ### What’s new in 2.1
>
> **Third-party library upgrades**.
>
> We’ve upgraded to the
>   latest stable releases of other third-party libraries wherever
>   possible. Some notable dependency upgrades in this release include:
>
> - Hibernate 5.3
> - Micrometer 1.1
> - Spring Data Lovelace
> - **Spring Framework 5.1**
> - Tomcat 9
> - Undertow 2

Answer (score 6):

**JDK Version Range**

- Spring Framework 5.3.x: JDK 8-19 (expected)
- Spring Framework 5.2.x: JDK 8-15
- Spring Framework 5.1.x: JDK 8-12
- Spring Framework 5.0.x: JDK 8-10
- Spring Framework 4.3.x: JDK 6-8

For more info please visit here [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions)