# Spring Boot Java 11 missing run time dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot

Running my Spring boot project in Java 10 and maven everything ran fine.  Simply changing the JDK from 10 to 11 introduced the following error

```
 emailer_1        | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultReactiveBootstrapConfiguration.reactiveVaultSessionManager
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
       | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultReactiveBootstrapConfiguration] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5d099f62]
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:680)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:577)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:562)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:620)
    emailer_1        |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:721)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:662)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1491)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1014)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:198)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:174)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:167)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.lambda$updateTypesIfNecessary$3(BeanTypeRegistry.java:154)
    emailer_1        |  at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:152)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:118)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:301)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:290)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:232)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:152)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    emailer_1        |  ... 36 common frames omitted
   emailer_1        | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactor.core.publisher.Mono
    emailer_1        |  at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    emailer_1        |  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    emailer_1        |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    emailer_1        |  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    emailer_1        |  ... 61 common frames omitted
```

I am not using the Spring Webflux framework, and have not needed any jars with the reactor framework before.  I know Java 11 gutted a lot of the JEE stuff out of the JDK, but this isn't that.

I have tried SpringBoot 2.0.5 release and the latest milestone release (M4) of 2.1 and the results are the same.  I have changed the Spring Cloud version from Finchley.SR1 to Greenwich.M1 with the same results.

Has anyone else ran into a similar problem?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: simply adding reactor core to my Pom as a managed dependency causes another issue of it not finding Netty libraries... which is weird because it should be using tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this, from Spring Boot documentation, Spring Boot 2.1.0.M4 and 2.0.5.RELEASE requires Java 8 or 9 and Spring Framework 5.1.0.RELEASE or above. So I don't think that Spring Boot **officially** supports Java 11 yet.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.M4/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html

Comment: Milestone 2 appears to have added it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1.0-M2-Release-Notes. Even then it would be weird for something to disappear from the class path.

Comment: You are right and I have seen that, but they have not reflected that in the reference manual yet.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.1.0 has been released with official support of Java 11. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53072662/3523579