# Spring boot 2.1.0 and Java 11 - JSP not loading

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot, java-11

I'm tired of investigating this issue, and I can not find a proper answer. Actually, I didn't find anyone using Java 11 and Spring. My JSP are not loading, it is simply as that. Some information about my project:

```
Spring Boot version: 2.0.5.RELEASE
Java version: 11
Gradle: 4.10.2
```

These are my application.yml properties:

```
server:
  contextPath: /mypath
  port: 9012
  display-name: my app
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: true
  tomcat:
    compression: on
    compressableMimeTypes: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
    # springboot 1.3+ compression
#    compression:
#      enabled: true
#      mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
    # enable HTTPS when running behind a proxy server
    remote_ip_header: x-forwarded-for
    protocol_header: x-forwarded-proto
  use-forward-headers: true
  # session timeout
  session:
    # spring time out set to 2hrs.
    cookie:
      max-age: 7200
    timeout: 7200
  # enabling SSL/HTTPS with spring boot
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: /mykeystorepath/keystore.ks
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-alias: selfsigned

http:
  mappers:
    jsonPrettyPrint: true

multipart:
  maxFileSize: 500MB
  maxRequestSize: 500MB
  fileSizeThreshold: 0

spring:
  application:
    name: appname
  jmx:
    enabled: true
    default-domain: ${spring.application.name}
  http:
    # enable and force http encoding support.
    encoding:
      enabled: true
      charset: UTF-8
      force: true
  mvc:
    favicon:
      enabled: true
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
      suffix: .jsp

management:
  server:
    port: 9512
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /manage

swagger:
  enable: false

endpoints:
  shutdown:
    enabled: true

#logging:
#  level:
#    org:
#      springframework:
#        web: DEBUG
```

My jsp files are in:

```
/parent-project-folder/my-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/
```

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /** The log. */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        springApplication.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "app.pid"));
        springApplication.run(args);

        LOG.info("--------------------------------------------------------------");
        LOG.info("--------- application startup complete --------");
        LOG.info("--------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer#configure(org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder)
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

I even tried to put my WEB-INF folder under /src/main/resources.

Next, this is the list of my dependencies (just a draft copy-paste):

```
apply plugin: 'war'

    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:gradle-git-properties:1.4.17'
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5"
        classpath "com.netflix.nebula:gradle-ospackage-plugin:4.4.0"
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.5.4"
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.17.0'
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:1.6.4"
        classpath 'com.github.samueltbrown:gradle-cucumber-plugin:0.5'

compile 'org.glassfish.corba:glassfish-corba-omgapi:4.2.0-b004'
        compile 'org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap:jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec:1.0.6.Final'
        runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator'
        compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
        compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1'
        compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0.1'
        compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'
        runtime 'javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0'

        compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
compile (group: 'org.owasp.esapi', name: 'esapi', version:'2.1.0.1') {
                exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics'
            }

            compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:${gsonVersion}"
            compile 'taglibs:standard:1.1.2'
            compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'

            compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot'
            compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
            compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
            compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
            compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
            compile 'com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:1.0.2'

            runtime  group: 'ph.samson.logback', name: 'logback-luhn-mask', version:'1.0.1'

            compile 'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:1.10'
            compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:1.8.3'
            compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.3'
            compile 'xalan:xalan:2.7.2'
            compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
            compile 'org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:1.5.7'
```

I have a login.jsp at the root, which I should be able like this https://localhost:9012/mypath/login.html, and it doesn't load.

UPDATE on Friday Nov 23

I'm making some progress. I will explain more about my app. Originally this app was written using Java 1.8 and Spring 1.5.9.RELEASE and BOMs for my development. The app used to have a GET controller under this path: "/login". And here comes the tricky part of it: whenever you hit the url "https://www.myapp.com/login.htm", in someway/somehow which I don't understand, Spring managed it to send the request for "login.htm" to the controller "/login". I'm not sure how it realized about the extra ".htm".

Now, as I'm using Java 11 and Spring 2.1.0.RELEASE, this doesn't work anymore. If I hit "/login" it goes to the controller. But I need to make a transparent migration, I can't change logic. This app serves requests, and the client side have been using "/login.htm" since years ago. I need to make "/login.htm" go to  "/login".

Comment: error trace please

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0.5 does not fully support Java 11. Spring 5.1 does. Wait for Spring Boot 2.1 GA or take the SNAPSHOT version. Most likely your problem will be resolved thereafter.

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov thanks, I will investigate a little. I have read some forums though and as you said looks like java 11 is not fully supported yet.

Comment: @want2learn there is no error in the stack trace at all. Just INFO messages. It is really stunning.

Comment: @Perimosh Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53072662/3523579

Comment: spring 2.0.5 has an illegal access in java 11.  I had to exclude the spring-boot-start-logging artifact. That got me running a standalone jar, but I still can't get it to work with tomcat 9 and eclipse.

Comment: People: I updated a little the question. Thanks to everyone! @MikhailKholodkov

Comment: @MarkD please see

Comment: @want2learn please see

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you run your application in tomcat. So check java version it uses. If the version is less then application java version, tomcat just doesn't run it.