# After upgrading Java to 11 I get ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

I upgraded my project from Java 8 to Java 11 and received

`Error: java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

while building the project. Everything seems working properly but I do not know how I get such kind of error. Do you have any idea about that?

In order to run the project I use `Run/Debug Configurations` -> `Spring Boot` -> `Application` -> `Run`

Here is the error message :

[image]

Comment: What version of IntelliJ is that? Also, how does your project look like (modular or non-modular)? How do you run it?

Comment: Intellij version is 2018.3.2. the latest version. My project consists of 4 different modules where I made the compilation of 4 modules by Java 11 . I am using Spring Boot to run the application. Spring Boot version is 1.5.10.RELEASE

Comment: Is it a modular project? (has `module-info.java`?) and can you update the question with your resultant command line for the run?

Comment: yes it is a modular project which consists of modules in the pom.xml such like <modules> <module>A</module>..... </modules>

Comment: @user2307786 I meant the java module system's module. Anyway I get that it's just a non-modular project, that you're trying to run. Just make sure that you're using a [compatible version of `spring-boot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427248/minimum-spring-version-compatible-with-java-11) possibly `2.1.0` and above.

Comment: `Spring Boot version 1.5.10.RELEASE` does not support Java 11

Comment: which version of Spring Boot you advise me to use ? I used Spring Boot version 2.1.1.RELEASE but it's same.

Comment: @user2307786 Please update that in the question as well. Also, as asked previously, could you update the question with your resultant **command line** for the run?

Comment: hi kaptan.it fixed my issue