# Spring batch java 11

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-batch, java-11

Hi guys How I can implement the Spring Batch processing with the Already present ArrayList of Product with JPA and Hibernate for save operation.I found most of the examples with csv file reading and batch processing but In my case there is no csv file I've already ArrayList of Product...where Product is entity class having some fields.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.x reached end of life. For Spring Boot 3.x you need Java 17. See https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot/#support and https://endoflife.date/spring-boot#java-compatibility

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum Spring version compatible with Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427248/minimum-spring-version-compatible-with-java-11) . Answers linked to the thread specifies the spring-boot version too.